# Retrive or Restore Elastic Beanstalk Config File

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I retrieve/restore my Elastic Beanstalk config file?

My hard-drive failed and I lost my Elastic Beanstalk config yaml file. I've looked around the eb CLI to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to know your environment variables its under

> Your EB Environment -> Configuration -> Software